# Easy Riddles #1 - Who lives in the white house?

Tags: lateral-thinking

Mr. Blue lives in the blue house, Mr. Pink lives in the pink house, and Mr. Brown lives in the brown house. Who lives in the white house?

*I don't know why, but I'm obsessed with easy riddles.*

Comment: Prolog says false:
?- livesIn(white,X).
false.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it:

> The President of the United States

Comment: Oh i was just starting this time:P

Comment: Yessss lol. Are these riddles so easy that they're annoying? Idk if I should continue posting like this.

Comment: Don't know really but personally i like these

Comment: They're somewhat easy yes, but not annoying. It does change the dynamic a bit in terms of having to be quickest to answer (somewhat like Stack Overflow). I'm not sure of whether there's any guideline on PSE that puzzles must be of a specific difficulty (e.g. each puzzle must result in 1% of hair being pulled out in frustration), maybe that's a good question for Meta.

Comment: D-mn, ninja'd :o)

Comment: But the president of the US is **Mr. Tramp** not **Mr. White**.

Comment: Mr. Tramp :P Troll.. LOL..

Comment: Funnily enough, the one who lives in the white house is mr. orange :)

Comment: Now that's starting to sound like a Tarantino movie :-)

Comment: YESSSSS lol..now that's funny

Comment: Comment: the President of The United States lives in the **W**hite **H**ouse. The question was who lives in the **w**hite **h**ouse. How do we know that **the** white house in the question is the White House.

Comment: I went by the lateral thinking tag. When I see that tag, I read the question to myself to hear how it "sounds". A fair number of riddles hide a twist when asked verbally, so to a question of "Who lives in the white house?" when asked verbally, a response of POTUS would be quite accurate.

Comment: FWIW I'm not very keen on these super-easy riddles (and for this particular one I have to say I think "Mr White" is just as good an answer as POTUS is) but they certainly aren't forbidden. If the PSE community decides it really hates them they'll start getting more downvotes than upvotes...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan - quite true, hence my earlier comment about maybe getting some guidance on Meta as to puzzle difficulty. I'm not sure community self-policing will itself be a deterrent.

Comment: Hmmm. Then why isn't the one who lives in the [Pink House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casa_Rosada) the President of Argentina?

Comment: I'd say its probably because its not as globally known or as famous a popular culture reference as the White House.